# Nearest distance between point and line layers in QGIS-3

Tags: qgis, proximity

I have a line layer with a road network and another point layer. I would like to connect the points to the nearest line in the other layer. I have tried to use the Vector analysis > Distance to nearest hub, but that only works if both layers are points, at least as far as I can see. I can't convert my line layer to points because the dataset is to big. (I tried but got errors.)
When searching here I have found others solutions, but they don't seam to work in Qgis 3.10.

I'm new to using Qgis in this way. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem? I'm running QGIS 3.10.4.

Comment: What is wrong with `v.distance`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When I use v.distance it only maps to one specific point, which is not the closest point in the road network. I have my point layer as 'from vector layer' and my line layer (road network) as 'to vector map'. I when use upload to_att to one column in the point layer, taking the value from the road network. Is this correct?